# flexbox: vertically center two divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a modal in the center of the screen that has an header.
That header must contain a title and the button to close it.

```
--------------------------------
|                       (close)|
|  Text                        |
|                              |
--------------------------------
```

So basically I have two requirements:

1. Every text inside the header must be centred vertically.
2. Be able to position the "(close)" close to the header in the corner.

Right now I have everything vertically centred but the elements I put inside the header for ma pile:

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|  Text                        |
|  (close)                     |
|                              |
--------------------------------
```

```css
.modal-payment__wrapper {          // <- this is the whole box
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';

}

.modal__header {                  // <- this is the header
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.modal__header__title {          // <- this is "text"
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-srhink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-payment__background">
    <div class="modal-payment__wrapper">
        <div class="modal__header">
            <div>
                Text
            </div>
            <div class="modal__header__x"
                @click="closeModal">
                x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__body">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Lt8bct5x/1/

Comment: `flex-direction` should be `row`if you need those elements aligned next to each other. Then use `align-items` to vertically center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a few errors in the code provided, but I think this is what you need. I had to remove the @click since that's not recognized here.

```css
.modal-payment__wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';
}

.modal__header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal__header__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

.modal__header__x {
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-payment__background">
  <div class="modal-payment__wrapper">
    <div class="modal__header">
      <div class="modal__header__title">
        Text
      </div>
      <div class="modal__header__x">
        x
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can do it like this. See comments in code to get where you are doing mistakes are what was left.

```css
.modal-payment__wrapper {        
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'sans-serif';

}

.modal__header {        
 
    display: flex;   // You need this
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;   // You need this
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  
}

// You will need below css
.modal__header > div{
  justify-content: space-around;   
  width: 50%;  
  align-self: center;   
 
}

.modal__header__title {          // <- this is "text"
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;  // Spelling mistake
    flex-basis: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.modal__header__x{
  color: #fff;  // You need this
  
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-payment__background">
    <div class="modal-payment__wrapper">
        <div class="modal__header">
            <div class="modal__header__title">
                Text
            </div>
            <div class="modal__header__x"
                @click="closeModal">
                x
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__body">
           BODY
         </div>   <!-- Missing /div in your code -->
  </div> <!-- Missing /div in your code -->
</div> <!-- Missing /div in your code -->
```